# Hide commit button column in MudTable

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am experimenting with the MudTable component and I was wondering if there is a way to hide the commit button column when inline editing is not in use. Currently I am using the default example and it looks like the last column goes on forever which looks a bit ugly.
the example for reference:

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Dense="@dense" Hover="@hover" ReadOnly="@ronly" CanCancelEdit="@canCancelEdit" Filter="new Func<Element,bool>(FilterFunc)"
          @bind-SelectedItem="selectedItem1" SortLabel="Sort By" CommitEditTooltip="Commit Edit"
          OnCommitEditClick="@(() => Snackbar.Add("Commit Edit Handler Invoked"))" RowEditPreview="BackupItem" RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues"
          RowEditCommit="ItemHasBeenCommitted" Bordered="@bordered" IsEditRowSwitchingBlocked="@blockSwitch" ApplyButtonPosition="@applyButtonPosition">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <ColGroup>
    
        <col style="width:50px;" />
        <col style="width:80px;" />
        <col style="width:50%;" />
        <col />
        <col />
        @if (applyButtonPosition.DisplayApplyButtonAtEnd())
        {
            <col style="width:2px;" />
        }
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Number)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Sign)">Sign</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Name)">Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Position)">Position</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Molar)">Mass</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Sign" Required />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Name" Required />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position">
            <MudNumericField @bind-Value="@context.Position" Required Min="1" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Molar" Required />
        </MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
```

[image: the last colum stays blank and is used for the commit button when inline editing is enabled]

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what you mean? The commit button is hidden when inline editing mode is not in use by default, so I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: @JesseGood I have attached an image. The last column always stays there whether in editing mode or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following css:

```
::deep .mud-table-bordered .mud-table-container .mud-table-root .mud-table-body .mud-table-row .mud-table-cell:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-right: none;
}
```

I'm assuming you are using CSS isolation, but if not remove the `::deep`.

Comment: where would you place this code though?

Comment: In a css file. If you use [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you can create a file like the following `MyComponent.razor.css` and put it in there. (Of course make sure to replace `MyComponent` with the name of your razor file.)